# Concatenate indices of each Numpy Array in a Matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have a Numpy Array with a bunch of numpy arrays inside of them. I want to group them based on the position in their individual array.

For Example:
If Matrix is:

`[[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]`

Then the code should return:

`[[1, 2, 4, 6], [2, 3, 5, 7]]`

This is becuase `1, 2, 4, 6` are all the first elements in their individual arrays, and `2, 3, 5, 7` are the second elements in their individual arrays.

Anyone know some function that could do this. Thanks.

Answer in Python.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Comment: Is the matrix always rectangular? Have you check numpy indexing and slicing? Or zip?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy.ndarray.T

Answer (score 1):

Using [numpy transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) should do the trick:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]])
a_t = a.T
print(a_t)
array([[1, 2, 4, 6],
       [2, 3, 5, 7]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data as a list:

```
In [101]: alist = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]                                             
In [102]: alist                                                                                
Out[102]: [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

and as a numpy array:

```
In [103]: arr = np.array(alist)                                                                
In [104]: arr                                                                                  
Out[104]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
```

A standard idiom for 'transposing' lists is:

```
In [105]: list(zip(*alist))                                                                    
Out[105]: [(1, 2, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5, 7)]
```

with arrays, there's a transpose method:

```
In [106]: arr.transpose()                                                                      
Out[106]: 
array([[1, 2, 4, 6],
       [2, 3, 5, 7]])
```

The first array is (4,2) shape; its transpose is (2,4).